# Adding footer to report causes erros [MS Access 07]

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a form that opens a report based on two combo boxes. It is opening an invoice for shipments. You can either open the report based on customer or shipment. Everything works fine for shipments and the total for all items is added correctly. However when I add a grand total within the page footer I am suddenly unable to open the form because access asks what the total is. I have a attached a picture to help explain better.

[image: Explination]

Comment: Does the detail footer not load before the page footer?

Comment: You're trying to sum a calculated field. MS doesn't store the values of calculated fields so this isn't going to work. Instead of sum(Text34) try sum([record source of textbox 34]), so if text34 is =(nz([TL],0)+nz([TM],0) you would do SUM(nz([TL],0)+nz([TM],0)).

Comment: Ah, I usually use the `NZ` function.. except I got lazy this time and used sum!  Mark this as an answer and i'll add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access does not store the values of calculated fields. As a result you can't sum the values that it produces. Instead of summing the calculated field, sum the calculation used to produce it.

example:

```
textbox24 = nz([TL],0) + nz([TM],0)
```

to sum this field use:

```
sum_field = sum(nz([TL],0) + nz([TM],0))
```